# Enviar multiplas chamadas para soap em php

Tags: php

Eu estou estudando o uso do SOAP no PHP, e eu tenho um webservice que quando eu envio o numero da matricula de um funcionário ele retorna o nome do funcionário e o setor, mas eu gostaria de enviar 5 numeros de matriculas ao mesmo tempo e retornar o nome de 5 funcionários, como eu posso adaptar meu codigo atual que envia apenas um numero por vez ?

Meu codigo:

```
<?php

$params  = array("soap_version"=> SOAP_1_2,
                "trace"=>1,
                "exceptions"=>0,
                );

$client = @new SoapClient('http://webserviceteste.com.br/WebService/WebService.asmx?WSDL',$params);

$retval = $client->ObterCadastro_S(
    array(
        'matricula'  => '0000',
        'inscricao'  => '0000',
    )
);

echo $retval->ObterCadastro_SResult->NomeFuncionario;
echo $retval->ObterCadastro_SResult->SetorFuncionario;

?>
```

Codigo para array de 3 parametros

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

//array que guarda 'matricula' => 'inscricao'
//'0001' => '1234',

$arrayMatriculasInscricoes = array("dados" => array("matricula" => 0001, "inscricao" => 1234, "cpf" => 123456789));

echo $arr["dados"]["matricula"];
echo $arr["dados"]["inscricao"];
echo $arr["dados"]["cpf"];

foreach ($arrayMatriculasInscricoes as $i => $inscricao) {

    //faz a consulta
    $retval = $client->ObterCadastro_S(
        array(
            'matricula'  => $i,
            'inscricao'  => $inscricao
        )
    );
    echo $retval->ObterCadastro_SResult->NomeFuncionario;
    echo $retval->ObterCadastro_SResult->SetorFuncionario;
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Valew

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar uma laço de repetição, segue:

no exemplo a seguir, é necessário que os arrays estejam em ordem mútua.
no ex: matricula=0001, inscricao=99999, qualquerCoisa=34563, variavel=34534

```
$arrayMatriculas = array('0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0005');
$arrayInscricoes = array('99999', '88888', '77777', '66666', '55555');
$arrayQualquerCoisa = array('34563', '34532', '23414', '45756', '45675');
$arrayVariavel = array('34534', '56753', '23435', '36786', '34567');

foreach ($arrayMatriculas as $i => $matricula) {

    //faz a consulta
    $retval = $client->ObterCadastro_S(
        array(
            'matricula'  => $matricula,
            'inscricao'  => $arrayInscricoes[$i],
            'qualquerCoisa' => $arrayQualquerCoisa[$i],
            'qualquerVariavel' => $arrayVariavel[$i]
        )
    );
    echo $retval->ObterCadastro_SResult->NomeFuncionario;
    echo $retval->ObterCadastro_SResult->SetorFuncionario;
}
```

Comment: Legal, e se caso eu quiser enviar o numero da matricula e a inscricao, como eu posso fazer ?

Comment: ai tem que ver se sua função ObterCadastro_S recebe a variável $inscrição. tem como você postar essa função aqui?

Comment: Na realidade eu preciso passar a matricula e inscrição, como eu posso fazer ?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem... hoje você consegue enviar esses dois valores? se sim, poste o código aqui.

Comment: Eu editei o codigo da minha pergunta, eu preciso enviar a matricula juntamente com a inscricao do funcionario para que o sistema me retorne o nome do funcionário.

Comment: editei minha resposta.

Comment: não, ai indico estes link para você entender o funcionamento de arrays e de laços em php. segue [link] http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) e (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)